# How to represent Callback in UML Class Diagram

Tags: java, callback, uml

I have an Interface say

```
Interface ICallback {
    public void informFunction();
}
```

I have a Class say:

```
Class Implementation implements ICallback {

   public Implementation() {
      new AnotherImplementation(this);
   }

   @override
   public void informFunction() {
      // do something
   }

}
```

Now consider a class where in the instance of Class Implementation is passed as a interface and is used to make a callback.

```
Class AnotherImplementation {
   public ICallback mCallback;

   public AnotherImplementation(ICallback callback) {
      mCallback = callback;
   }

   public void testFunction() {
     mCallback.informFunction();  // Callback
   }
}
```

Now I want to know how I can design a UML Class Diagram. **Most importantly I need to know how to represent Callback Functionality that will happen in the Class AnotherImplementation :: testFunction().**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your code is represented in the following class diagram:

[image]

It represents the relationships between the classes:

- `Implementation` implements `ICallback`
- `Implementation` depends on `AnotherImplementation` (it creates one in its constructor)
- `AnotherImplementation` has a `ICallback` (named mCallback)

A class diagram does not represent method functionality. Method functionality is visualized with a sequence or a Collaboration diagram.

In your example, the sequence diagram for `testFucntion()` is very simple:

[image: sequence diagram]

Note that the `Implementation` class does not show in the sequence diagram. This happens because the `mCallback` member is declared as `ICallback`. It could be anything that implements the `ICallback` interface.

I think that the more interesting question is how to visualize the method that triggers the callback. You don't mention which method of `Implementation` calls the `testFunction()` of `AnotherImplementation`, so I guess that this happens inside the constructor of `Implementation`. I created the following sequence diagram for this constructor:

[image: callback sequence]

Here you can see:

1. `Implementation` creates the `AnotherImplementation`
2. `Implementation` invokes `testFunction` on `AnotherImplementation`
3. `AnotherImplementation` invokes `informFunction` on `Implementation`

Comment: The class diagram and explanation is just awesome. Could you please tell which tool have you used for creating/generate this class diagram.

Comment: The tool that I use is bouml is free, another could be Draw.io, another StarUml